# new Intent not starting from Service ( Tried all solutions from Google)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is how my activity is defined in the AndroidManifest.xml file:-

```
<activity android:name=".MyDialog"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

How my service is defined :-

```
  <service
        android:name=".ChatHeadService"
        android:process=":chatHead"/>
```

How I call it from Service:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyDialog.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Still the activity doesn't start ! Please Help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

from inside the Service class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyDialog.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent );
```

Comment: What is dialogIntent ?

Comment: @M.S.P are you there sir ?